# Handle infinite loop in componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

I am using a simple form with a text input. When something is written the state of the component is updated, and as `this.setState` is asynchronous, I fetch the data from the API on `componentDidUpdate`.

The problem is that I don't find the solution to avoid the infinite loop, as I update the state after using axios:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchValue: "",
      data: null,
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({ searchValue: event.target.value });
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    const url = 'https://www.google.com/?search=' + this.state.searchValue;
    axios.get(url).then(response => this.setState({data: response.data}));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you want to fetch new data on input change, you can make the call directly in `handleInputChange` callback.

```
handleInputChange({target: {value}}) {
  this.setState({ searchValue: value });
  this.fetchData(value);
}

fetchData(text) {
  const url = 'https://www.google.com/?search=' + text;
  axios.get(url).then(({data}) => this.setState({data}));
}
```

Now, if you want to use `componentDidUpdate` you can compare `previousState` with your state.

```
handleInputChange({target: {value}}) {
  this.setState({ searchValue: value });
}

fetchData(text) {
  const url = 'https://www.google.com/?search=' + text;
  axios.get(url).then(({data}) => this.setState({data}));
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // only update if searchValue has changed
  if (prevState.searchValue !== this.state.searchValue) {
     this.fetchData(this.state.searchValue);
  }
}
```

Also with hooks:

```
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

function handleInputChange({target: {value}}) {
   setSearchValue(value);
}

function fetchData(text) {
   const url = 'https://www.google.com/?search=' + text;
   axios.get(url).then(({data}) => setData({data}));
}

useEffect(() => {
  // don't run on componentDidMount or if string is empty
  if (searchValue) {
    fetchData(searchValue);
  }
}, [searchValue]);
```

**Update 2021**

The above implementations work fine, but there is a slightly better way to handle the request inside `useEffect`:

```
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    
    function handleInputChange({target: {value}}) {
       setSearchValue(value);
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData(text) {
         try {
            // don't run on componentDidMount or if string is empty
            if (text) {
              return
            }

            const url = `https://www.google.com/?search=${text}`;
            const { data } = await axios.get(url);
            setData({ data });
         } catch(e) {
           // handle error
         }
      };

      fetchData(searchValue);
    }, [searchValue]);
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally got the solution, trying the second choice. Just using `prevProps.searchValue !== this.state.searchValue` instead.

Comment: `searchValue` shouldn't be on `prevProps`. Can you log both `prevProps` and `prevState` and paste the results?

Comment: You are correct. I was having the infinite loop. You were totally correct in your answer, which is I am using.